# Why is orgmode creating a new/duplicate PROPERTIES section with a new ID?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

This morning I noticed that in the agenda view my Habit graphs were not showing but Habit view was turned on. When I looked in my actual org files, I saw that new PROPERTIES sections had been created:

```
*** TODO Clean Toothbrush thingy
    SCHEDULED: <2015-10-18 Sun .+1m>
    :PROPERTIES:
    :ID:       48388d21-bf85-4d88-b7ea-6dd9ca40f6b9
    :END:
    :LOGBOOK:
    - State "DONE"       from "STARTED"    <2014-01-01 Wed 18:35>
    :END:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :ID:       2031B102-0202-4F53-A4FD-329C0021A837
    :STYLE:    habit
    :LOGGING:  DONE(!)
    :END:
```

It seems as though: 1) OrgMode has suddenly changed it's preference of the ordering of PROPERTIES and LOGBOOK and 2) When out of order, it's created a new PROPERTIES section where it wants it. (I believe the new PROPERTIES sections were created by `M-x org-mobile-push`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true and described in [latest release notes:](http://orgmode.org/Changes.html) *Properties drawers are now required to be located right after a headline and its planning line, when applicable.*
On that same page is the definition of a function **org-repair-property-drawers** which will repair them.